# Drawing on a transparent image in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, png, draw, transparent

If i draw a line or some figure on a transparent image(4 channels) with a certain colour, after i save the image, the line/figure it's white, even though i draw with a red colour and i create a transparent image or i open one from internet. I'm missing something. Any suggestions?

Original picture
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDlWq.png

Picture after drawing 2 lines with red colour
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqmaR.png

```
    Mat image;
    image = imread("ball.png", -1);

    if(image.channels() == 4)
    {
        //vector<Mat> ch;
        //split(image, ch);

        cv::line(image,cv::Point(0,0),cv::Point(image.cols,image.rows),CV_RGB(255,0,0),7,CV_AA,0);
        cv::line(image,cv::Point(0,image.rows),cv::Point(image.cols,0),CV_RGB(255,0,0),7,CV_AA,0);

        imwrite("out.png", image); 

        cv::namedWindow("Transparent", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE|CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
        cv::imshow("Transparent",image);
        waitKey(0);

        Mat temp(image);
         cv::line(temp,cv::Point(0,0),cv::Point(temp.cols,temp.rows),CV_RGB(255,0,0),7,CV_AA,0);
        cv::line(temp,cv::Point(0,temp.rows),cv::Point(temp.cols,0),CV_RGB(255,0,0),7,CV_AA,0);
        double opacity = 0.9;
        cv::addWeighted(temp,opacity,image,1 - opacity,0,image);
        cv::namedWindow("opacity",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cv::imshow("opacity",image);
        imwrite("opacity.png",image);
        waitKey(0);



        string path="myimage.png";
        Mat myImage(image.rows,image.cols,CV_8UC4);
        myImage=cv::Scalar(255,255,255,0);
        cv::line(myImage,cv::Point(0,0),cv::Point(image.cols,image.rows),CV_RGB(255,0,0),7,CV_AA,0);
        cv::line(myImage,cv::Point(0,image.rows),cv::Point(image.cols,0),CV_RGB(255,0,0),7,CV_AA,0);
        imwrite(path,myImage);
```

I've tried all this 3 methods and all result in the same picture.

Comment: you need to show some code...

Comment: does CV_RGB(255,0,0) create a RGBA color? And I'm not sure whether openCV handles transparency correct when reading/writing images.

Comment: Yes! Before i save the picture, i display it with the imshow function and the image has the lines red, but after i save it, and opened it the lines are white.

opencv handles transparency ok with imread called with the second parameter -1 (CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED). Check this link http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread

Comment: I think `imshow` doesnt handle alpha channels correctly, and CV_RGB() macro creates a scalar with 0 entries for each entry after the RGB values. I'll give you an answer in a second.

Comment: imshow doesn't handles alpha channels, that's right. That's why when i call it, the transparent image isn't transparent, it has black background, but this doesn't bother me since, since i want the saved picture to be transparent with an x on it, and not the displayed one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the macro `CV_RGB` creates you a `cv::Scalar` with entries `(b,g,r,0)`.

this code works for me:

```
    cv::line(image,cv::Point(0,0),cv::Point(image.cols,image.rows),cv::Scalar(0,0,255,255),7,CV_AA,0);
    cv::line(image,cv::Point(0,image.rows),cv::Point(image.cols,0),cv::Scalar(0,0,255,255),7,CV_AA,0);
```

with this result:

[image]

Comment: Silly me, i had to realize that this was the problem. Thank you kind sir!